# Accessing Photos from Posts in Google + using API?

Tags: php, google-plus, picasa

I am trying to build a server side application (PHP) which can download photos that has been shared with me in Google +, but I couldn't find a method in Google+ PHP Client Library for this. I tried to get it through PicasaWeb API, but the Album 'Photos from posts' is not listed when trying to get the list of all albums.
Please suggest some way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fetch the posts themselves.  In there will be the URLs for the photos that you can then fetch to get the actual images.

Note that there are "resize" tags in the image URL path so if you see something like `.../s2048/...` or `.../w497-h373/...` then that will instruct G+ to give you a smaller version (which greatly reduces bandwidth and latency over requesting the full-size image and scaling it locally).  Just remove that component of the path to get the full-size image.